# nsDialogs::Show accepts ENTER key even if all buttons from UI are destroyed

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

I have a small bootstrapper with custom UI, which contains two pages, one to configure the install, and the other showing a progressbar for the download and install of the payload.
My problem:
If the user presses Enter key when in the second page, the installer exits, even if it didn't finish installing.

I removed all the controls I could from the UI with:

```
GetDlgItem $1 $HWNDPARENT 1 //(2, and 3)
System::Call `User32::DestroyWindow(i $1)`
```

in the onGuiInit function, and the first page ignores enter and space keys now, but the second page still exits on Enter key.
I have no other components on that page except some labels, a progressbar, and a slideshow (nsisSlideshow plugin).
In the background I have a thread which downloads and installs the payload.

The pages are declared like this:

```
Page Custom Options_Show Options_Leave
Page Custom Progress_Show Progress_Leave
```

So, long story short, when I press enter, the nsDialogs::Show function returns, killing the installer.

Any way I can stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should try to stop forward page changes by calling `Abort` in the page leave callback function.

NSIS only blocks clicks from buttons that exist **and** are disabled.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
Page Custom Options_Show #Options_Leave
Page Custom Progress_Show #Progress_Leave

Function DisableBottomButtons
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1
ShowWindow $0 0
EnableWindow $0 0
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2
ShowWindow $0 0
EnableWindow $0 0
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 3 
ShowWindow $0 0
EnableWindow $0 0
FunctionEnd


Function Options_Show
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateButton} 0 20 100% 12u "Go to next page"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 GoToNextPage
Call DisableBottomButtons
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function GoToNextPage
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1
EnableWindow $0 1
SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_COMMAND} 1 0
FunctionEnd


Function Progress_Show
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateButton} 0 20 100% 12u "Exit"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 ExitApp
Call DisableBottomButtons
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function ExitApp
MessageBox mb_ok "Bye"
; Faking a click on Next/Close will not work when the button is disabled, 
; this uses a slightly ugly trick to bypass that. GoToNextPage does it properly.
!define /math WM_NOTIFY_OUTER_NEXT ${WM_USER} + 0x8
SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_NOTIFY_OUTER_NEXT} 1 0
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks @Anders. Following your advice to not destroy the buttons, and disabling them instead, now it works!
So, I removed the code that destroyed the buttons, then in Options_Show and Progress_Show, first thing is to disable the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

First, small code snippet:

```
!macro EnableNextButtonM IsEnable
    Push $1
    GetDlgItem $1 $HWNDPARENT 1 ;next button
    EnableWindow $1 ${IsEnable}
    Pop $1
!macroend
!define EnableNextButton "!insertmacro EnableNextButtonM"
```

Then, in function Progress_Show  you should call

${EnableNextButton} 0

**before**

nsDialogs::Show

to disable **Next** button before it will be shown.
After download completion (at the download callback) call

${EnableNextButton} 1

to enable it again.

You variant with .onGuiInit does not work because it calls once - before first page will be shown. But every next page will be created dynamically again, thus, all UI page must be implemented into page custom -Pre function.

Comment: Thanks @Serge , tried it, but it still quits on enter.

Comment: And, it seems the Next button doesn't exist. Since I've destroyed it in onGuiInit method. GetDlgItem returns 0.

Comment: I tried adding another button, and setting it as default. Still nothing.

Comment: Do not remove controls, just disable it.

Comment: And you can halt transition calling Abort in Progress_Leave

Comment: Could you try to override  .onUserAbort? (call Abort in it)?

Comment: Thank you, but onUserAbort didn't work. The installer is finished by Enter key, not aborted.